# Table cell value accessing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have an html table. Where each table row contains several input text areas and each input text area has unique ids assigned by javascript dynamically.Now I want to put all that ids of the 1st column of my table into an array. I am facing problem in this matter. Help me please.

Html code of my table is as follows:

```
<table id="POITable">
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>UOM</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
    </tr>

    <tr style="visibility:hidden;">             <!-- This is just a dummy row-->
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><img alt="Icon" src="/assets/add-icon.png" id="addmorePOIbutton" onclick="insRow()" /></td>
        <td><img alt="Icon" src="/assets/minus-icon.png" id="delPOIbutton" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text"/></td>
        <td><img alt="Icon" src="/assets/add-icon.png" id="addmorePOIbutton" onclick="insRow()" /></td>
        <td><img alt="Icon" src="/assets/minus-icon.png" id="delPOIbutton" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now my javascript code to put the ids of the input text box is:

```
  function make_summary()
  {
    var arr=new Array();
    var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
    var size=x.rows.length;

    for (i=2;i<=x.rows.length-1;i++)
    {
      var each_row=x.rows[i];
      var each_col=each_row.cells[1];
      console.log(each_col);   
    }
  }
```

I can access each table data, I mean the td tag, But since there is `<input>` tag inside each td tag,so how to access that input tag element?

`each_col.getElementByTagName();` is not working. It is throwing error.

Please give me some solutions. Please give me only javascript solutions (no jquery please).

Comment: `each_col.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]` or `each_col.querySelector('input')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there's always only one element in your `td` tags, you can just access the inner element with

```
each_col.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

Remember that `getElementsByTagName()` returns a HtmlCollection, not a single element - so you have to specify which of the elements you want to target.

BTW... There's no method called `getElementByTagName()` - this might be where the confusion comes from. It's the plural of Element -> Elements

```
getElementsByTagName()
          ^
```

Comment: Thank you very much @mmm